# How to initialize the Transport Service in Eclipse UpdateSite

Tags: eclipse, p2

when invoking the load method of UpdateSite,

UpdateSite.load(updateSiteURI,(RepositoryTransport) agent.getService(Transport.SERVICE_NAME), new NullProgressMonitor());

The argument 
 (RepositoryTransport) agent.getService(Transport.SERVICE_NAME) is returning null always.

any way to get the Transport service ?

Comment: Also i tried checking the 'Generate Metadata repository' option while exporting the product.

Comment: `UpdateSite` is an internal class so you should not be using it.

Comment: I'm having a data in the following location :

http://10.0.3.114:8015/buildTools/Feat_APt_1.0.0.201407241618/

and the here is my code:

HttpURLConnection con =(HttpURLConnection) new URL(URLName).openConnection();
         con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
         return con.getResponseCode() 

I'm always getting the error code as '301'. If i give invalid URL then it is returning 404 (which is correct) but if i give the correct URL path im getting 301.

Comment: @greg-449: why con.getResponseCode() returns '301' even though the URL is a valid one ?

Answer (score 0):

The bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf provides the default `Transport` service implementation of p2. So you need to make sure that you have included this bundle and its dependencies in your RCP/OSGi runtime.